# git - make a 'fresh' feature branch while preserving current feature branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

With respect to git.

I've got a feature branch we'll call `foo`. In there are a number of committed changes and some uncommitted changes to implement a feature.

I've made a bad assumption and a lot of what's in `foo` is no longer desirable.

I'd like create a new feature branch, `bar` without any of the changes applied to `foo` and manually re-implement the bits that are useful from `foo` into `bar`.

Once `bar` is good I'll delete the `foo` branch.

How can I create the new feature branch without any of what's in `foo` (a fresh start) while preserving what's in `foo` so that I can review it as necessary ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just switch to `master` and branch from there again.

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b bar
```

You'll have to commit any uncommitted changes before doing that, though.
(You can stash, but I do not think it is a good idea in this case).

Comment: Thank you. I just worked this out but you've explained it better than I did. I'll accept the answer once I'm able to (some sort of time limit in place currently). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout -b bar <commit>
```

Where `<commit>` is the commit from which you want to branch off. To find that commit, you can inspect the history graph yourself with a command like:

```
git log --decorate --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
```

To find that commit programmatically (assuming you branched off from `master`):

```
git merge-base foo master
```

Comment: OK ! that's more than I need right now but very useful information - thank you.

Comment: Just as a note, `--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit` is the same as `--oneline`.

Answer (score 0):

OK answering my own question. Where I'd gone wrong is that when creating the new branch I was still in the feature branch and so I was picking up the current state of `foo`.

By committing all that was in `foo` and then checking out `master` I was able to create `bar` and have a fresh start.